# Jackson DateFormatter set timezone without changing time

Tags: java, jackson, simpledateformat

I have a problem with jackson. 
I have a date in the database in the following format :
2018-01-01 13:00:00

I convert the Database entry to a "Date" object.

I now want the jackson objectmapper to print it out date in the following format like :
2018-01-01T13:00:00.000+0200

Now I have the following code where I set up my objectmapper

```
private static ObjectMapper init() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
    mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    return mapper;
}
```

Now the problem is, that the date is printed out like this :
2018-01-01T15:00:00.000+0200

While formatting the date and adding the timezone information, it calculates the new time. All my dates use the "Europe/Berlin" timezone but I don't save it with this information in the database.

Is there any way how to add the timezone information without changing the time?

Regards

Comment: Which database you are using? You can set the time to "Europe/Berlin".

Comment: Looks like more of a DateFormat issue rather than a jackson issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a custom DateFormat class, where I can handle the formatting.

**Very important :** 
You have to implement the "clone" method. If you use Eclipse it only shows an error for the missing format and parse method. The clone method was missing and i got some nullpointer exceptions at the DateFormat class.

```
mapper.setDateFormat(JsonDateFormat);

public class JsonDateFormat extends DateFormat implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
        // TODO DO STUFF
        return toAppendTo;
    }

    @Override
    public Date parse(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
        // TODO DO STUFF
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        return new JsonDateFormat();
    }

}
```